# Generate Solr Indice Using Customized Mapper in MapReduce

Tags: solr, mapreduce

I have some data in HDFS. The looks like:

```
ID Details
1 AA#BB#CC
2 AB#BC#CD
```

The details filed uses # as delimiter to separate different fields. I want to generate the solr indices by fields. For example, I need indices on Field1:AA, Field2:BB, Field:CC with ID1.

I searched online, there are lots of methods to do the file indices in mapreduce. But my requirement is different. I need indics on different fields. So do anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the solrj API.

First, define a POJO for the fields of the class. Use the annotation (`@Field`) provided by the solrj.

In the mapreduce, read the data (value part) and create the objects of the POJO, using the data. You are already aware of how to split the data and assign to each field (member) in the POJO.

Now create an instance of the `SolrClient` type, get the binder using (`getBinder()`), convert the POJO object into the `SolrInputDocument` using `toSolrInputDocument()` on the `binder`.

Now create an object of `UpdateRequest` and add the `SolrInputDocument`s into it. Process the request using the `SolrClient` object.

Hope this will help.

Comment: So I need to do all the SolrClient and UpdateRequest things in my reducers? Do you have a sample code to this? Thanks a lot in advance!!!!

Comment: @ChengChen I don't have access to computer. You can try it. In the mapper in you put the logic, because you know the formatting for the input data.